# Export Jaspersoft Dashboard to PDF (already working with phantomJS for PNG)

Tags: jasperserver

I have a strange problem, I can export my dashboard to PNG but I can't export it in any other format (PDF, DOCX, PPT, ...).

When I try to export in PDF, I have a 403 error (forbidden), is it normal that I can export to PNG but not in PDF ?

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the Jaspersoft Support and after a live debugging session, the support found that the Temp folder at the organization level wasn't here (deleted during the setup of Jasperserver because we thought that it was useless), this Temp folder should have ROLE_USER permissions (all permissions).